# Как я могу решить проблему TypeError: not enough arguments for format string в mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb

Вот мой код:

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://LOGIN:PASS@cluster0.ye4cx.mongodb.net/info?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE")

mydb = myclient["info"]
mydb.comics.create_index([{"title": "text"}])
find = mydb.comics.find({"$text": {"$search": "Zombies"}})

for f in find:
    print(f)
```

Он выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так, уже второй полтора дня бьюсь с этой бедой

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564974/cant-create-index-due-to-typeerror-not-enough-arguments-for-format-string

Comment: Зачем писать ответ, редактируя текст вопроса? Удалите ответ из вопроса и запостите, пожалуйста, ответ в виде ответа и примите его как правильный, нажав на птичку! Не издевайтесь над сайтом и сообщетвом!

Comment: Хорошо, я просто пользуюсь сайтом 2ой, максимум 3ий день, спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: Все, через 18 часов смогу принять правильный ответ, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась вот так:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import TEXT

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://LOGIN:PASS@cluster0.ye4cx.mongodb.net/info?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE")
mydb = myclient["info"]
mycol = mydb["comics"]

mycol.create_index([('title', TEXT)], default_language='english')

find = mycol.find({"$text": {"$search": "68"}})

for f in find:
    print(f)
```